# Automating a set a of weekly reports, including graphs and delivery of reports

Tags: python, pandas, hash-map, matplotlib

I have been writing code to automate some weekly reports. I had [help over on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754503/creating-a-new-set-of-dataframes-from-dictionary). I have code that works for the most part, however there are a few things that I just can't seem to fix.

In short, I loop through the data and create a dictionary of dataframes based on 'location' key unique values. I can use the dictionary to make summary reports for each location. I wanted to make another dictionary from this based on 'sublocation.' Instead with some advice, I make a list of each sublocation, access each item in the df-dict, loop to find corresponding sublocations and make plots.

My problems are as follows:

1. Code is slow
2. Graphs are not formatted properly (overlapping even with tight_layout)
3. For the reports in sublocation, I am having a hard time saving to the right folder. I think this has to do with the way I want to format the string in the savefig text. For each sublocation I want reference the name using value['location'], I think this is always updated every loop so it doesn't work.
4. I have the error exception because when looking to match subloc to loc. not every subloc will appear in the dict value dataframe

```
f = 'path'
d = pd.DataFrame()
d= pd.read_csv(f)
dfs = dict(tuple(d.groupby('location')))
for key, value in dfs.items():
    try:
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3);
        sns.countplot(y='ethnic', data=value, orient='h', palette ='colorblind', ax=axs[0,0]);
        sns.countplot(y='Ratio', data=value,orient='v', palette ='colorblind',ax=axs[1,0]);
        sns.countplot(y='site', data = value, ax=axs[0,1]);
        sns.countplot(y='STATUS', data = value, ax = axs[1,1])
        sns.countplot(y='Assessment', data = value, ax = axs[0,2])
        #pth = os.path.join(tmppath, '{0}'.format(key))
        for p in axs.patches:
            ax.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2., p.get_width(), '%d' % int(p.get_width()), 
            fontsize=12, color='red', ha='center', va='bottom')
        plt.tight_layout(pad=2.0, w_pad=1.0, h_pad=2.0);
        plt.set_title('{0}'.format(key)+'Summary')
        plt.savefig("basepath/testing123/{0}/{1}.pdf".format(key,key), bbox_inches = 'tight'); 
        plt.clf()

        #plt.show()
    except:
        plt.savefig("basepath/{0}/{1}.pdf".format(key,key), bbox_inches = 'tight');
        #plt.savefig("{0}.pdf".format(key), bbox_inches = 'tight'); 
        pass

#####Now for sublocations

dfss = dict(tuple(d.groupby('site')))

#%%

for key, value in dfss.items():
    a =(repr(value['school_dbn'][:1]))

    try:
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3);
        #tmppath = 'basepath/{0}'.format(key);
        sns.countplot(y='ethnic', data=value, orient='h', palette ='colorblind', ax=axs[0,0]);
        sns.countplot(y='Program]', data=value,orient='v', palette ='colorblind',ax=axs[1,0]);
        sns.countplot(y='AltAssessment', data = value, ax = axs[0,2])
        pth = os.path.join(tmppath, '{0}'.format(key))
        plt.tight_layout(pad=2.0, w_pad=1.0, h_pad=2.0);
        plt.set_title('{0}'.format(key)+'Summary')
        plt.savefig("basepath/{0}/{1}_{2}.pdf".format(value['location'][-6:],value['location'][-6:],key), bbox_inches = 'tight'); 
        plt.clf()

        #plt.show()
    except:
        plt.savefig("basepath/testing123/{0}/{1}_{2}.pdf".format(value['location'][-6:],value['location'][-6:],key), bbox_inches = 'tight');
        #plt.savefig("{0}.pdf".format(key), bbox_inches = 'tight'); 
        pass
```

The reason why I want to save like this is because each location has a folder with same name. Sublocation belongs to only one location, therefore I want to save as 'location_sublocation.pdf'.

Comment: So is the code working as intended? If not, this question is [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Linny for the most part it is working, aside from the saving the second part correctly and slowness. Frankly the ugly plots are something I think I can fix but just included there for suggestions. 

Perhaps there is a faster way to perform these procedures, they are rather simple, essentially just filtering. Do you think this is better for overflow?

Comment: Try building this script in an interactive environment so you can play around with data and graphs without running it everytime. Check out Jupyter. All the issues except slowness can be fixed by searching for answers.

Comment: @user14492  I am using jupyter lab and notebook. Currently trying out making the subplots differently, and might just settle with saving the second set of files in some other directory and write a script to move all of them to the appropriate places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this done by making a second dictionary, which takes locations as keys and values as list of sublocations

```
dfs = dict(tuple(data.groupby('location')))
dfss = dict(tuple(data.groupby('sublocation')))

dd = {}

for key, value in dfs.items(): #dictionary is made of groupby object, key is 
                               #location, value is datafram
    a = []
    dee={}
    for i in value['sublocation']:
        if i in a:
            pass
        else:
            a.append(str(i))
    dee = {key:a}
    dd.update(dee)
for key, value in dfss.items(): 
    try:
        for k, v in dd.items():
            if key in v:
                dur=str(k)
            else:
                pass
    except:
        pass
```

Then in the next cell,

```
for key, value in dfss.items(): 
    try:
        for k, v in dd.items():
            if key in v:
                dur=str(k)
            else:
                pass
        #tmp = value[value['sublocation']==i]
        sns.set(style='white', palette=sns.palplot(sns.color_palette(ui)), font='sans-serif')
```

I think I can make the overall script run even faster by employing more regex expressions for filtering the dataframe in various steps.

This set-up works because I can save the files according to the key's from the two dictionaries. It allows me to save the nearly 375 files automatically. I use another script to move the files to their respective folders.

```
plt.savefig("path/{0}/{1} @ {2}.pdf".format(dur,dur,key), bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

Having a slightly different case, take three data sets and make mini data sets based on some column such as location

```
oct_dict = dict(tuple(oct.groupby('location')))
oct2_dict = dict(tuple(oct2.groupby('location'))) 
for k, v in oct_dict.items():
    #try:
        #v2 = stu_dict[k]      #sometimes using this try/else method works better
    #else:
        #v2 = pd.DataFrame()
    #try:
        #v3 = oct2_dict[k]
    #else:
        #v3 = pd.DataFrame()
    for k2, v2 in stu_dict.items(): #replace with v2 = stu_dict[k] if you know for sure it exits
        for k3, v3 in oct2_dict.items(): #replace with v3 = oct2_dict[k] if you know for sure it exits
            if k == k2 and k == k3: #can delete this if not needed
                plt.close('all')
                with PdfPages(r'path\{}.pdf'.format(k)) as pdf:
```